# bind .keyup to dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, bind, dynamic-data, keyup

I have seen a bunch of questions on this but im still stumped. I could realy use some help understanding what im doing wrong here.

(my terminology may not be correct below)

I have a textarea and a .keyup function bound to it by class name

This first textarea fires the function fine

I then add a second textarea dynamically which is intended to fire the same function

**My .keyup function**

```
$('.trans').keyup(function() {
    alert("Working");

});
```

I understand that the above doesnt work on the newly created textarea because it wasnt part of the DOM when the function was bound. I have tried several ansers to other questions but cant seem to get this working:

**Other things Ive tried:**

```
// I also tried this   
// Neither textarea responds if this is used     
 $('.trans').on('keyup', '.newTrans', function() {
    alert("Working");
 }); 


// I also tried this 
// Only the first textarea responds    
 $('.trans').delegate('.newTrans', 'keyup', function(){
   alert("Working");
 });
```

Here is a JSfiddle with more of the code im using if needed:

[jSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedD0D/VFt6X/2/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) isn't going to work in your fiddle at all because you have specified an old version of jQuery from before `.on()` was introduced.

If you upgrade to a newer version of jQuery (at least 1.7) you can do this:

```
 $(document).on('keyup', '.trans', function() {
    alert("Working");
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VFt6X/4/

If you need to keep using v1.6.4 for some reason then use the [`.delegate()` method](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead:

```
 $(document).delegate('.trans', 'keyup', function() {
    alert("Working");
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VFt6X/5/

Note that either way the `'.trans'` selector for the elements you care about is passed as a parameter to the function. The `$(...)` part on the left has to specify some container that already exists. I've used `document`, but it is better to specify something closer to the elements in question if possible, so in your case you could use `$("#centerNotes")`.

Comment: DelightedD0D uses jQuery 1.6.4 on jsFiddle

Comment: Thanks @Heejin, yes, I just noticed that when I went to update it.

Comment: I do need to stick with v1.6.4. As they both work, what is the difference between  `$(document).delegate` and `$('.trans').live` Heejin uses below?

Comment: Well `.live()` is deprecated and has been removed as of version 1.9, so best not to use it so that if you upgrade to newer jQuery in future you don't have to change your code. But also `.live()` is less efficient than `.delegate()` due to the way it's implemented, so I wouldn't use `.live()` unless you have to use a version of jQuery older than 1.4.2 where you can't use `.delegate()`. There are several specific drawbacks to `.live()` listed on [its doco page](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.trans').live('keyup', function() {
    alert("Working");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VFt6X/3/

Comment: +1, This method did work. Accepted above because it helped me better understand what I was doing wrong.